# Настройка горячих клавиш WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

Не могу понять, но у меня не работает ctrl + C, если я нажимаю эту комбинацию то ничего не копируется, пропадает выделение, а самое противное, что курсор становится  на весь символ, приходится нажимать "insert".

Кто знает как это поправить и вернуться к нормальному состоянию?

Comment: у Вас *IdeaVim* плагин не установлен случайно? Проверьте список установленных плагинов в *Settings | Plugins*. Если он там есть, выключите его и перестартуйте WebStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация по keymap на английском https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.2/settings-keymap.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Коротко и нужное так:

> Обратите внимание, что предопределенные комбинации нередактируемы. Когда Вы переопределяете ассоциации в первый раз, PhpStorm автоматически создает копию выбранных предопределенных ключей, которые становятся редактируемыми.

После этого появляется кнопка RESET (справа вверху) - и по ней сказано, что:

> Кликните по этой кнопке для отмены изменений в кастомной конфигурации и восстановления конф. по-умолчанию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем default:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте нужно удалить папку `config` из `/home/user/.phpstorm`
Настройки сбросятся по умолчанию.